# создание миграций yii2 на бд postgres

Tags: yii2

При выполнении миграции(метод up):

```
public function up()
{
    $this->execute('CREATE SEQUENCE auto_inc_battle_players');

    $this->createTable('battle_players', [
        'id' => 'INT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval("auto_inc_battle_players")',
        'name' => 'VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL',
        'PRIMARY KEY (id)',
        'UNIQUE (name)'
    ]);
}
```

Получаю ошибки:

```
    > execute SQL: CREATE SEQUENCE auto_inc_battle_players ... done (time: 0.004s)
    > create table battle_players ...Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message                                 'SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "auto_inc_battle_players"        does not exist
    The SQL being executed was: CREATE TABLE "battle_players" (
    "id" INT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval("auto_inc_battle_players"),
    "name" VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (name)
    )'

    in /var/www/yii.loc/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:664

    Error Info:
    Array
    [0] => 42703
    [1] => 7
    [2] => ERROR:  column "auto_inc_battle_players" does not exist
```

Неужели нельзя такие запросы совместно истользовать?
Т.е. На создание SEQUENCE и TABLE необходимо генерировать отдельные миграции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Postgres в двойные кавычки заключаются объекты (колонки, таблицы и прочее) а строки только в одинарные, аргументом функции является строка, значит ее наддо писать в одинарных кавычках.
И так двно уже не пишут, всегда используют тип serial чтобы не писать так много https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/11/datatype-numeric